# Relation between limit and limit with probability

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, infinity

It's obvious that, for a finite constant $c^*$ and a sequence $\{X_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, the following two cannot be both true.

- $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{X_n} = +\infty$
- $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{X_n} = c^*$

---

### ***REVISION & EDIT***:

In repsponse to Karl's comment, we can suppose $X_n(\omega)$ is a function from a sample space, $f:\Omega \to X$. With the usual probability space {$\Omega, E, P$}, the limit notation $\lim\limits_{n}{X_n} = a$ is equivalent to saying that

$$ \lim\limits_{n}X_{n}(\omega)=a, \forall \omega \in \Omega \\
\iff
Pr(\lim\limits_{n}X_{n}=a ) = 1 
\wedge \nexists \{ M_0 \in E \ | \ 
Pr( \lim\limits_{n}X_{n}=b) = 0, X_n:M_0 \to X \} $$

where $a \ne b$.

With this clarification, the answers to following questions now seem to be obvious by themselves.

---

My questions are as followings.

### ***Question 1***:

Can the following two be both true?

- $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}X_{n}(\omega) = +\infty, \forall \omega \in \Omega $
- $ Prob( \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{X_n} = c^* ) = 1$

Or vice versa, can the following two be both true?

- $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}X_{n}(\omega) = c^*, \forall \omega \in \Omega $
- $ Prob( \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{X_n} = +\infty ) = 1$

And why or why not?

### ***Question 2*** (the weaker version):

Can the following two be both true?

- $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}X_{n}(\omega) = +\infty, \forall \omega \in \Omega $
- $ Prob( \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{X_n} = c^* ) = 0$

Or vice versa, can the following two be both true?

- $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}X_{n}(\omega) = c^*, \forall \omega \in \Omega $
- $ Prob( \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{X_n} = +\infty ) = 0$

Why or why not?

Comment: No, you can take the general case of probability on propositions. A proposition $P$ is impossible if and only if $Pr(P)=0$, here impossible means contradiction. $P$ can be any sort of proposition (logical).

Comment: If the $X_n$ are random variables, then "$\lim X_n=c$" is an event with a probability, not a statement that can be true or false. So your questions don't make sense.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost This is misleading, it suggests that a null event is impossible. This is not something probability theory asserts

Comment: @Karl What if "lim $X_n$ = $c^*$" is a given event (or: condition), would that make sense? In that case, would it probably be reduced to a trivial question? The  answer would simply be "no"?

Comment: @andrewzhang, it's not if you take the null event to be the empty set. Even if you don't, it doesn't  make the theory inconsistent. It's much more reasonable in the context of probability over propositions. You are using terms out of context, whereas my comment gives the usual way propositional probability is used. Possible/impossible (modal logic), probable/improbable (Probabilistic logic), contradiction/tautology (propositional/FOL).

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost If you take all null events as empty you are developing your own  Probability Theory.

Comment: @geetha290km, like I said, you (and Zhang) are comparing apples and oranges. Look up probability on propositions - regardless, the issue here is of semantics (technical meaning intended), neither "theory," nor language.

Comment: @Karl Please the REVISION & EDIT that I added. Does this make sense now? Thanks very much for your comment.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost With the clarification that I added in the Revision&Edit, I believe the answers now align with your comment above. I much appreciate your comment.

Comment: "$E$ is certain" is another way of saying "$P(E)=1$". But you can't write this as just "$E$". $E$ is an event, not a statement. If you mean to ask about a conditional probability, you should use conditional probability notation $P(A|B)$.

Comment: @Karl I re-thought about it and I decided not to ask about the conditional probability any more. In the Revision&Edit section, I had added the complete statement in terms of "random" variable $X_n$. There "$ \lim\limits_{n}X_{n}(\omega)=a, \forall \omega \in \Omega$" should be a standard statement now.

Comment: @Karl I have also re-edited all statements in questions. Now it seems the answers should be trivial and obvious. If you still see questions, or any statement, that doesn't make sense, please let me know.

Comment: The answers to all questions seem to be "no" now. Even the weaker version cannot be true. As we state that "$\lim\limits_{n}X_{n}(\omega)=a, \forall \omega \in \Omega$", it implies not only $P(\lim\limits_{n}X_{n}=a) =  1$, but also that the probability null set cannot exist. Am I understanding all this correctly now? If not, someone please do help me get this right.